# $a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$: Prove the following Equation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, fractions

I have trouble solving following problem:

Given the sequence:

$$a_n=\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n$$

We have to show that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \Big(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\Big)^{n+1} \frac{n+1}{n} , n \in \mathbb N$$

I would really appreciate any help and I hope everything is correctly written.

Greetings

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Comment: Start with $a_k = (1+1/k)^k$ and plug in $k = n+1$ to get $a_{n+1}$. Divide this by $a_n$ and try to simplify. A useful expression for simplifying is to use that $x^{n} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}n^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{2n+2}}=$$
$$=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{n^2+2n}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I really appreciate it.